# Increase Char value by one

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
char buf[] = {0x45, 0x76, 0x72, 0x23, 0x12};
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<=sizeof(buf); ++i){
      printf("%c\n", buf[i]); 
    }
}
```

What I want to do is take `buf[i]` when it is printed out and and make 0x45 read 0x46. Essentially, how do I add 1 to each value as it is going through the for loop?

Comment: The conditional part of your for loop should be i<sizeof(buf). Now you are accessing one element too much. The answers have the same error ;)

Comment: No, I tried it and loose my last character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `+`

```
for (i = 0; i<sizeof(buf); ++i){
  printf("%c\n", buf[i] + 1); //  print the incremented value
  //printf("%c\n", buf[i]++); //  increment the printed value

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be i<sizeof(buf)?

Answer (score 3):

You add 1 to it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char buf[] = { 0x45, 0x76, 0x72, 0x23, 0x12 };
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++)
      printf("%c\n", buf[i] + 1);
}
```

As simple as that!

If you want the value in the buffer changed as well as printed, then you probably use `++buf[i]` in place of `buf[i] + 1`.

Note that if `char` is a signed type and the value stored in some element of the array is equivalent to `0xFF`, then adding one to it is undefined behaviour (though you'll most likely print an ASCII NUL `'\0'`).